# In Python programming I got this error while trying to get_by_url_prefix

Tags: python, mapping

My code is given below:

```
return cls(**Database.find_one(StoreConstants.COLLECTION, {'url_prefix':{"$regex": '^{}'.format(url_prefix)}}))
TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
```

Answer (score 0):

The `**` operator expects a dictionary and your code seems to return `None`.

So appearently your `Database.find_one` does not return anything.

Comment: @classmethod
    def get_by_url_prefix(cls,url_prefix):
        return cls(**Database.find(StoreConstants.COLLECTION, {'url_prefix':{"$regex": '^{}'.format(url_prefix)}}))

Comment: this is my code return the data and it is also stored in data base but still show this error